# how to know KBs of document in a document library in Sharepoint 2007?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

I have a website in Sharepoint 2007. I need to do a query of documents in a document library in a SPWeb/site and to know the KBs of the document.

In fact, i have to extract which is the url of the document from a linkfield and then look for the KBs?

Anyone can provide the query? or the method? Can i do this with a SPSiteDataQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a field with the internal name File_x0020_Size (SPBuiltInFieldId.File_x0020_Size = {8fca95c0-9b7d-456f-8dae-b41ee2728b85})

You can probably use that to do a query against the files size.

Comment: Finally I used FileSizeDisplay in my query. I have written another question to ask for any improvement, thank you.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634321/could-this-query-to-get-the-size-of-a-doc-be-improved-in-sharepoint-2007

Answer (score 0):

If the above answer does not do it for you, you can use the object model to figure it out.    The SPListItem has a File property which is a SPFile object.  That has a Length property which is the file size/length in bytes.  Obviously this approach requires iterating each SPListItem.

Comment: Finally I used FileSizeDisplay in my query. I have written another question to ask for any improvement, thank you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/634321/could-this-query-to-get-the-size-of-a-doc-be-improved-in-sharepoint-2007